# Run function after all images inside a container are loaded

Tags: image, callback, load

I'm loading a couple of images individually inside a container to fade them in but want to run a function after all of theme are loaded, tried a couple of approaches but none of them worked.

I thought about store the sum of the fading images as they appear to compare them with the lenght of the img tags, so when they were equal I could run the function.

```
$(.container img).each(function () {
        $(this).attr("src", $(this).data("src"));
        $(this).on('load', function () {
            $(this).addClass("modal-imgs-in");
        });
    });
```

That's how I'm loading the images and it`s working fine.

Thanks in advance (:

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Promises, specifically Promise.all, to queue a task for when multiple other things are done.

```
Promise.all([...document.querySelectorAll(".container img")].map(
  img => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    img.src = img.getAttribute("data-src");
    img.onload = ()=>resolve(img);
    img.onerror = ()=>reject(img);
  })
)).then(imgs => {
  console.log("Images loaded: ", imgs);
}).catch(img => {
  console.error("Failed to load: ", img);
});
```

This replaces jQuery with vanilla JS (which will therefore be much more performant), getting the relevant images and mapping them to a Promise, which will resolve when the image is loaded, or reject if it fails to load.

`Promise.all` then resolves when all of the individual promises have resolved, and will be passed all of the loaded image tags. If any of them fail to load, then `catch` receives the first image that failed to load.